# admin-on-rest: custom route spinner

Tags: reactjs, progress, admin-on-rest

I have added my own custom route.  Within the custom route I am loading my own custom component and I'd like to use the admin.state.loading flag to display a spinner while my component loads it's data.  For example, I'm calling my restClient from the componentWillMount for my component within the custom route:

```
componentWillMount() {
      restClient(GET_LIST, `facilityuserconversations/${username}`, {
        filter: {},
        sort: {field: 'updated', order: 'Desc'},
        pagination: {page: 1, perPage: 9999},
      })
        .then(result => {
          // I'd like to see a loading spinner while I wait on these results.
        });
    }
```

How do I show the admin-on-rest spinner while my rest results are loading?

I am currently using:

```
"admin-on-rest": "^1.2.3"

"react": "~15.5.4",
"react-redux": "~5.0.4",
"react-router": "~4.1.0",
"redux": "~3.6.0",
```

Comment: Add more information. React version, react-router version, are you using any state management such as Redux?

Comment: Just render `<Spinner />` there is one here https://github.com/chenglou/react-spinner